# How do I set NaN values in pandas dataframe to another column under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, where one of the column is an integer `id`, and there are two other columns `start` and `end` which have floating point representation.

Some `end` values are `nan`. I want to set these `end` values that are `nan` to `start` for certain `id`, e.g., `id == 1`.

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"id": [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
"start": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
"end": [1.1, float("nan"), 1.3, 1.4, float("nan")]
})
```

Afterwards, it should be

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"id": [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
"start": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
"end": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, float("nan")]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Main trick is to get a boolean index that selects when you have the desired ID and has a nan value. We use `.isin()` for multiple ID selection and `isnull()` to check for NaN values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        "start": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        "end": [1.1, float("nan"), 1.3, 1.4, float("nan")],
    }
)

# For multiple id numbers
ids = [1] 

indexer = df["id"].isin(ids) & df["end"].isnull()

df.loc[indexer, "end"] = df.loc[indexer, "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr `df.end = df.end.fillna(df.start[df.id==1])`

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     {
   ...:         "id": [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
   ...:         "start": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
   ...:         "end": [1.1, float("nan"), 1.3, 1.4, float("nan")],
   ...:     }
   ...: )

In [3]: df.end = df.end.fillna(df.start[df.id==1])

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   id  start  end
0   0    1.1  1.1
1   1    1.2  1.2
2   1    1.3  1.3
3   2    1.4  1.4
4   2    1.5  NaN
```